# Can I declaratively bind an ItemsContol.ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, mvvm

I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.  I've got a simplified piece of Xaml that looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.MainPage" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Background="Black" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl x:Name="PictureItemsControl"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Pics}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Location}" 
                                   Height="200" 
                                   Width="200" 
                                   Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" 
                                       FontSize="16" 
                                       Foreground="White" 
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the codebehind for my MainPage.xaml, I have this:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public FooViewModel viewModel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new FooViewModel();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }

    }
}
```

And my ViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class FooViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Pic> Pics;
        public FooViewModel()
        {
            Pics = new ObservableCollection<Pic>();
            Pic.GetPics(Pics);
        }

        //More code here... 
    }
}
```

And Pic is just a simple class that has some public properties and a static method that fills an observable collection with test data.  The problem is that I'm not seeing any binding happening in my ItemsControl UNLESS I add this line to my MainPage constructor:

```
PictureItemsControl.ItemsSource = viewModel.Pics;
```

If I do that, the binding works.  But this doesn't seem right to me.  Am I missing something in the declarative binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change "Pics" to be a property, not a field.  You cannot directly databind to a field.  Change Pics to:

```
public ObservableCollection<Pic> Pics { get; private set; }
```

The working case works because you're binding to your ViewModel, and Pics indirectly.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it had to be something easy and I must have overlooked that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to specify the ItemsSource on an ItemControl (ListBox, TabControl, ComboBox) to be able to bind data to it.

Comment: I don't understand your response.  I can bind to the ItemsSource in code, but the equilivent line of Xaml doesn't seem to work.  Can you be more specific about what I'm not including in the xaml?